# What order does SVN checkout files?

Tags: php, svn

I would like to know what order SVN checks out files, specifically on a clean checkout. I'm trying to run a script that depends on the filemtime() of certain files and if I could force some files to checkout on a fresh checkout before other it would make everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not specified in the Subversion documentation, I don't think you should depend on any particular order. Even if it behaves in a predictable way now, it might change in the future, as it doesn't seem like something they would need to guarantee. It might also depend on whether the data store is BDB or FSFS.

So if you need to check out files in a specific order, check them out individually in that order.

Answer (score 0):

without taking a look at the source code of a repository, I would imagine in the same order the hosting OS renders the filename(s) in a directory search. I would imagine it iteratively goes through a directory and grabs all files, does a version check and issues them to the client. I suppose you could hack it by explicitly doing an update in the order you'd like them received.

Answer (score -1):

Typically it goes something like

```
/1/2/3/4/
/1/2/3/5/
/1/2/3/6/
/1/2/7/8/
/1/2/7/9/
/1/10/11/
/1/10/12/
/13/14/
```

and so on. Get it?

Comment: You example looks a lot like alphabetical order. If I do an "ls -l" I see the dirs in alpha but the svn checkout is clearly not happening in alpha order.

Comment: Does for me. Alpha and into the directories first, if set to recursive.. maybe it depends on other things?